# PHP varying queries with binding params. pgSQL VS MySQL prepared statements | ?,?,? VS $1, $2, $3

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

In MySQL you can use `?` to bind each variable in a statement, the nice thing about this is that the `SQL` string doesnt care which order the variables are bound in the statement. In `pgSQL` I find that the variables are required to have a `$(number) - (e.g. $1,$2,$3)`. This makes the statement inflexible and requires the statement to have all variables or else `$2` would become `$1` if its missing.
Example:

```
Table: apples

| apple_id | name |  color  | cost |
----------------------------------
|     1    |   A  |   red   | 1.50 |
|     2    |   A  |   red   | 1.60 |
|     3    |   C  |   red   | 1.70 |
|     4    |   D  |   blue  | 1.80 |
|     5    |   D  |   blue  | 2.50 |
|     6    |   F  |   gold  | 3.50 |
|     7    |   G  |   green | 4.50 |
|     8    |   H  |   green | 5.50 |
------------------------------------

//MySQL Version

//COMING FROM CLIENT | MAY BE NULL IF FILTER NOT SET

$color = "";
$name = "";
$vars = 0;
$and = "";

if(!empty($_POST['color']){
   $color = "color = ?";
   $vars++;
}
if(!empty($_POST['name']){
   $name = "name = ?";
   $vars++;
}

if($vars > 1){
   $and = "and";
}

$sql = "SELECT apple_id,name,color,cost FROM apples WHERE ".$color." ".$and." ".$name.""
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

if(!empty($_POST['color']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['color'],$_POST['name']);

}elseif(!empty($_POST['color'])){
//color can be position 1
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['color']);

}elseif(!empty($_POST['name'])){
//name can be position 1
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$name,$color,$cost);
while($stmt->fetch()){
//blah blah
}
```

pgSQL

```
$color = "";
$name = "";
$vars = 0;
$and = "";

if(!empty($_POST['color']){
   $color = "color = $1";
   $vars++;
}
if(!empty($_POST['name']){
   $name = "name = $2";
   $vars++;
}

if($vars > 1){
   $and = "and";
}

$sql = "SELECT apple_id,name,color,cost FROM apples WHERE ".$color." ".$and." ".$name.""
$result = pg_prepare($conn, 'query' ,$sql);

if(!empty($_POST['color']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
//this works if both filters are set.
    $result = pg_execute($conn,'query' , array($_POST['color'],$_POST['name']));

}elseif(!empty($_POST['color'])){
//this works if only color is set
    $result = pg_execute($conn,'query' , array($_POST['color']));

}elseif(!empty($_POST['name'])){
//this fails
    $result = pg_execute($conn,'query' , array($_POST['name']));
}
while($assoc = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
//blah blah
}
```

I realize I could go through the effort of seeing which variables are not empty before, and assisn `$_POST['name']` to `$1` if its the only one, but this is a very simple example. I have other examples where there are 4 variables.
Is there an easier way to do this? Or a more flexible way to bind the variables?

Comment: The "easier way" if it is an option, is probably to [use PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of either `pg_*()` or mysqli. PDO would present a common interface for both, and allow you to use named parameters `color = :color, name = :name`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Your comment should be an SO answer. Beautiful!

Comment: @dakis No, "you should use a different technology entirely" is itself never a very good _answer_ for SO even if it is sometimes the best long-term solution.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: typically, a dynamically generated where clause starts static  `WHERE 1=1` and if we need to append to that, append a (leading) space, keyword AND, a space, and then the condition, so what gets generated looks like this: `WHERE 1=1 AND color = ? AND foo = ?`.   as far as "easier", no, its up to the code that is conditionally (dynamically) generating the SQL to also bind the appropriate values.  echoing previous comment, code using named placeholders can be more decipherable than code that uses positional ? bind placeholders, especially when there are more than a couple of them

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - can you provide a PDO example in an answer? I have not used PDO before

Comment: [Here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) is a very good PDO tutorial. And, optionally, I also recommend you the [article about error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).